# Finding the index of the vector for the sum of pairwise in R

Tags: r, combn

When I run this code

```
x <- c(2, 2, 10, 8)
combn(x, 2, sum)
```

I get

```
> combn(x, 2, sum)
[1]  4 12 10 12 10 18
```

How do I get the index for x for any of the combn?
For this question, the 4 is the sum of 2 + 2 which is x[1] + x[2]. I need the index [1] and [2] for x.

Comment: Maybe use `outer` insted of `combn`, `outer(x, x, "+")`? Then the row/column corresponds to the input index.

Comment: What is the exact expected output?

Comment: Another option : `'names<-'(combn(x, 2, sum), combn(seq.int(x), 2, toString))`

Comment: @sindri_baldur ... I'm doing a greedy search for a combinatorial problem. x is simply a column in my data frame. I need the index to refer to that row.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas and markus, I played around with "which" function with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

This code will give you the first element of the combination in the first line, the second in the second, and in the last line you'll get the sum:

```r
combn(x, 2, function(x) c(x, sum(x)))
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2   10
[2,]    2   10    8   10    8    8
[3,]    4   12   10   12   10   18
```

If you want the output as a `data.frame`:

```r
t(combn(x, 2, function(x) c(x, sum(x))))-> l
dimnames(l)[[2]] <- c(paste0("X",1:2), "Sum")
as.data.frame(l)
```

```r
  X1 X2 Sum
1  2  2   4
2  2 10  12
3  2  8  10
4  2 10  12
5  2  8  10
6 10  8  18
```

Comment: I'll apply to a bigger data set to determine efficiency, etc. At x with length of 4 may not be an issue. My real data may be in the thousands.

Comment: if you can `dput` a sample I can help with optimizing, otherwise you're always free to open a new question with efficiency as a goal

Comment: Thanks for the offer. This is for greedy search and to show and tell on R Shiny. I don't want to spend too much time on it. I need to formulate my problem and apply some type of optimization method. That will take some time.